# Splitting a dataframe into multiple dataframe based on entries in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a dataframe:

```
time | text
01.01.2000 | None
None | abc
None | cde
None | def
01.02.2000 | None
None | abb
None | bbc
None | dde
01.03.2000 | None
None | 123
None | 278
None | 782
```

I now want to split this dataframe in multiple dataframes beginning with the value where time is not None and adding the rows for each dataframe just one after another with a new line after each original row. That means it should look like this:

```
df1
time | text
01.01.2000 | abc \n cde \n def
```

And the second dataframe like this:

```
df2
time | text
01.02.2000 | abb \n bbc \n dde
```

How can I do this? I would like to use a for loop to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward fill `time` column then groupby `time` column

```py
df['time'] = df['time'].ffill()
out = (df.groupby('time', as_index=False)
       ['text'].agg(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna())))
```

```
print(out)

         time           text
0  01.01.2000  abc\ncde\ndef
1  01.02.2000  abb\nbbc\ndde
2  01.03.2000  123\n278\n782
```

```py
groups = [g for name, g in out.groupby('time')]
```

```
print(groups)

[         time           text
0  01.01.2000  abc\ncde\ndef,          time           text
1  01.02.2000  abb\nbbc\ndde,          time           text
2  01.03.2000  123\n278\n782]
```

Comment: Thank you! The filling works out fine, but I get this `ValueError: ValueError: Grouper for 'time' not 1-dimensional`.

Comment: An elegant solution, though this fails if the integers are not represented as strings. Adding `.astype(str)` after `x.dropna()` can prevent this.

Comment: @Tobitor You have two columns named `time`?

Comment: No, just one. My dataframe exists of the columns: `time` and `text`.

Comment: This line throws this error: `out = (df.groupby('time', as_index=False)
       ['text'].agg(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna())))`

Comment: @Tobitor What's the result of `df.head(10).to_dict()` after forward fill?

Comment: @Tobitor And what's the result of `df.columns`? Is it a multi-index columns?

Comment: Yes, it is MultiIndex columns. And the result of df.head(10).to_dict() is a dictionary. Do you need the exact dictionary? It looks like it is because the multi index, isn't it?

Comment: @Tobitor Problem is caused by multi-index columns which is not shown in your sample data.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I am sorry! I did not see it because of that... Did not see that I have multi index columns

Comment: I do not know how to get rid of the multi index columns...

Comment: @Tobitor How is dataframe generated?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', delimiter = "top - ", header = None)

Comment: @Tobitor How is the csv looks like, how about remove `header=None`?